# Using trig to determine angles from a compound cut

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

Trigonometry was never my strong point so any help would be much appreciated.

Below is an image of a solid square section bar with a compound cut at one end. Given the two angles $\alpha$ & $ \beta$ (which are measured from a plane perpendicular to the bar's neutral axis to an edge on the cut face), is there any way one can determine the angles $\gamma$ & $\theta$? Where $\gamma$ is the single cut angle from the imaginary plane to the face and $\theta$ is the amount the bar has to rotate so that the cut face is perpendicular to the sheet or worktop.

[image: Angled cuts]

I am looking for a mathematical solution to what is currently solved through empirical work which takes time. I wish to create a table for a metalworker to reference when receiving drawings that show compound cuts in an orthographic view ($\alpha$ & $\beta$)

Answer (score 2):

The cut plane is a span of two vectors:

$ v_1 $ is in the $xy$ plane, $v_1 = (\cos \beta, -\sin \beta, 0)$

$v_2 $ is in $yz$ plane, $v_2 = ( 0 , - \sin \alpha , \cos \alpha )$

Therefore, the normal vector to the plane is along $v_2 \times v_1$

$n = v_2 \times v_1 =  ( \cos \alpha \sin \beta , \cos \alpha \cos \beta , \sin \alpha \cos \beta )$

Angle $\gamma$ is the angle that $n$ makes with the $y$-axis,

$\gamma = \cos^{-1}  \dfrac{\cos \alpha \cos \beta }{ \sqrt { \cos^2 \alpha + \sin^2 \alpha \cos^2 \beta }} $

Finally when rotating the bar about the $y$-axis, the cut face plane becomes perpendicular to the $xy$ plane when the normal vector has zero $z$-component.

The rotated normal vector z-component  is

$-\sin \theta  \cos \alpha \sin \beta + \cos \theta  \sin \alpha \cos \beta = 0$

hence,

$\tan \theta = \dfrac{\sin \alpha \cos \beta }{  \cos \alpha \sin \beta} = \dfrac{\tan \alpha}{ \tan \beta} $

Using $\alpha = 35^\circ$ and $\beta = 65^\circ$ and the formulas above results in

$ \gamma = 66.093^\circ $

and

$\theta = 18.082^\circ$

Comment: wow, very comprehensive, thank you. I also found that tan **tan γ = tan B / cos θ**, so if you already have Theta, this could be a simpler solution.